# How to execute multiple tasks parallelly OR sequentially in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I was trying to execute multiple tasks parallelly.
Task it self is calling a S.P.

I had created another S.P in which I called multiple tasks.
But again to schedule it I had to create another Task.

Is there any simple way to do this.

Comment: You can make tasks run in parallel by making them child tasks of a common parent task. Once the parent task completes all of its child tasks will run in parallel

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you have to follow the approach you have used, as we can use a SQL or a SP only, in the CREATE TASK command.